# Est-ce que "combinatoire" est approprié ici ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, terminologie

Je travaille dans une société allemande et étant le seul français sur 900 personnes, on m'a demandé de valider cette phrase.

> Notre mode exprime la confiance en soi et **combinatoire**, par des
>   tensions, des contrastes, des harmonies, les multiples accords entre pièces.

Je n'ai pas la version originale en allemand.

Je trouve le mot `combinatoire` bizarre ici (note : je suis développeur, pas traducteur ni linguiste, et ça fait 9 ans que je ne parle plus français régulièrement).

J'ai lu grâce au copain Google, que la `combinatoire` (le substantif) relève normalement des mathématiques.

J'ai aussi lu que `combinatoire` peut être utilisé comme un adjectif, dans ce cas, peut-on dire :

> Notre mode exprime la confiance en soi, elle est combinatoire, etc.

Comment: Oui, j'ai aussi du mal à voir ce que peut être une *confiance combinatoire* mais aussi à comprendre comment une mode peut exprimer la confiance en soi par des tensions et des contrastes... Un peu plus de contexte aiderait ici.

Comment: Peut-être un "autocorrect" s'en est-il mêlé, et a remplacé "combine" par "combinatoire" ? ce serait intéressant de voir si le reste de la phrase a du sens dans ce cas: "Notre mode exprime la confiance en soi et *combine*, par des tensions, des contrastes [...]".

Comment: @jiliagre cette phrase est issue d'un texte de com' à destination de nos clients (marché du vêtement de luxe), et qui contient beaucoup de phrases un peu pompeuses pleines d'adjectifs qui sonnent bien (j'ai édité le post pour montrer la phrase dans son intégralité).

Comment: @Greg ce n'est pas impossible ! L'usage de "combiner" fait sens ici. J'ai demandé au service com' de me fournir le texte original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il me semble que la phrase ferait sens si on remplaçait "combinatoire" par "combine":

> Notre mode exprime la confiance en soi et combine, par des tensions, des contrastes, des harmonies, les multiples accords entre pièces.

Si le sens est correct, pour ma part j'utiliserais plutôt "associe" au lieu de "combine".

Comment: En effet, j'ai eu les versions allemande (originale) et anglaise (traduite de l'allemand). En Allemand `kombinierbar` se traduit littéralement par `combinatoire`, ce qui ne fonctionne pas en français. Pour la version anglaise, ils ont utilisé `to combine`. J'ai donc proposé aussi `combiner` voire `associer`, je reste aujourd'hui sans réponse du service com'... ça fait plaisir de se décarcasser ! :D